# Loading texture during run time OpenGL android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I will like to load textures during run time ( so I dont need to load all of the texture)

If I try to load a texture during run time with this function, I get the `RunTimeException` ( I think that is because the context is already created)

Is any way to do this without having 2 OpenlGL context(I read that this may cause error if the drivers are bad implemented)?

```
public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();                       
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't touched OpenGL ES in Java, only C++ but I would have thought this would be perfectly OK - are you trying to create this texture on a different thread to the thread you created the OpenGL context on? Did your OpenGL context creation code succeed?

Comment: So I need to create another OpenGL context in order to charge the texture and then use in the same one?

Comment: You should be able to use the same context to create all your textures at any time. You need to perform this all on the same thread as the one you created the context on.

glGetError() should provide some useful debugging information, stick that after each GL call and see which one breaks, once you have that information it might be a little clearer as to why its not working.

Comment: the comment of  @user4627255  worked for me :  **"You need to perform this all on the same thread as the one you created the context on"** -> on OpenGL android  this can be achieved with `GlSurfaceView.queueEvent`